# Invalid base 10 digit ArgumentError in Julia

Tags: debugging, package, julia, argument-error

I am continuing my project to create a function that corrects grammar, but it seems that every time I run it, it generates an ArgumentError.

My code:

```
function grmr(s)
    ws = split(s, " ")
    ss = ""
    for i in 1:length(ws)
        if parse(Int, ws[i])
            ws[i+1] = ItemQuantity(parse(Int, ws[i]), ws[i+1])
            ws[i] = ""
        elseif ws[i] in ["many", "multiple", "numerous", "several", "few", "some"]
            ws[i+1] = pluralize(singularize(ws[i+1]))
        elseif ws[i] in ["single", "a", "an"]
            ws[i+1] = singularize(ws[i+1])
        elseif split(ws[i])[end] == "s"
            ws[i] = pluralize(singularize(ws[i]))
        elseif ws[i] in ["a", "an"]
            ws[i] = indefinite(ws[i+1])
        end
        ss = string(ss, ws[i], " ")
    end
    return ss
end
```

I tried `grmr("I have a apple")` and `grmr("My favorite is a apple")` to make sure it corrects it to "I have an apple" and "My favorite is an apple", but both cases came up with an error like this:

```
ArgumentError: invalid base 10 digit 'I' in "I"
Stacktrace:
 [1] tryparse_internal(#unused#::Type{Int64}, s::SubString{String}, startpos::Int64, endpos::Int64, base_::Int64, raise::Bool)
   @ Base .\parse.jl:137
 [2] parse(::Type{Int64}, s::SubString{String}; base::Nothing)
   @ Base .\parse.jl:241
 [3] parse
   @ .\parse.jl:240 [inlined]
 [4] grmr(s::String)
   @ Main .\REPL[2]:5
 [5] top-level scope
   @ REPL[3]:1
```

For the "My favorite is a apple" one, it is the same error except the beginning is `invalid base 10 digit "M" in "My"`, so I realized it generated an error for the first character of the first word.
By the way, I'm using the EnglishText package, and yes, it is imported.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the loop you are calling `parse(Int, "I")` which produces the error you see.

The fact that you have written `if parse(Int, ws[1]` suggests to me that you were only looking to parse the string in certain situations, however the `parse` call will always be evaluated in the `if` clause.

Maybe you were looking for a `try ... catch` block to handle the error? Alternatively you could look into the `tryparse` function to do something like `if typeof(tryparse(Int, ws[i])) == Int` which will evaluate to `false` if parsing fails rather than erroring.

Comment: If you want a grammatically incorrect condition, you can use `tryparse(Int, ws[i]) isa Int` :)